# Fetching An Object Based On String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to fetch an object based on the name of the object provided as a string input. For example,

```
sunny = WeatherCondition(...)
rainy = WeatherCondition(...)
snowy = WeatherCondition(...)

weather = input("Enter one of three weather conditions -> sunny, rainy, snowy")
```

The value of the variable `weather` will be either sunny, rainy or snowy.
Based on this I'd like to fetch and assign one of the three objects to another variable.

I could simply define an instance attribute for class `WeatherCondition` but only if what I'm trying to achieve simply isn't possible.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Ugur, Is there any way I can simply get one of the three objects sunny, rainy or snowy whose name matches the string value of weather ?

Comment: Use a `dict` to *map* strings to other objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, the best approach here is to use a `dict` to map each weather type (sunny, rainy etc) to its respective `WeatherCondition` instance:

```
weathers = {'sunny': WeatherCondition(...),
            'rainy': WeatherCondition(...),
            'snowy': WeatherCondition(...)}
```

You can then access each `WeatherCondition` object like this:

```
weathers['rainy']
```

Since you're taking the weather type as user input, it'll look something like this:

```
weather = input("Enter one of three weather conditions -> sunny, rainy, snowy")
weathers[weather]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but is there any in-built method available that resolves a string name to an object name based on the LEGB scope ?